# "If you do..., then you are not..." vs "If you do..., then this is not the way of"

Tags: meaning, expressions, differences

I wish to know the difference between the following phrases that are in bold:

(1) If you know clearly that it is wrong, yet do not stand up and point out that, **then this is not the way of** someone who practices the truth.
(2) If you know clearly that it is wrong, yet do not stand up and point out that, **then you are not** someone who practices the truth.

I don't know their differences, could you help me out? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are learning English, then you may find that our sister site [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) is more suited to your needs.  If you are an English speaker, please clarify what you think they mean and why you find them confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second answer is more correct, however, "If you clearly know this is wrong, yet you do not point it out, you do not practice truthfulness." would be a better choice.

The first phrase does not fit the sentence,